# Simplest way to replace deprecated std::error::Error::description

Tags: rust

```
warning: use of deprecated associated function `std::error::Error::description`: use the Display impl or to_string()

error::Error::description(self)
```

Does this justify the whole `Display impl` boilerplate or can I can away with the simpler `to_string()`. What was in `description` that's now deprecated (and I will miss dearly because of its simplicity)?

Comment: Have you seen this? [Error::Description is deprecated](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/03/12/Rust-1.42.html#errordescription-is-deprecated): "Because `description` returns a `&str`, it is not nearly as useful as we wished it would be. This means that you basically need to return the contents of an `Error` verbatim; if you wanted to say, use formatting to produce a nicer description, that is impossible: you'd need to return a `String`. Instead, error types should implement the `Display`/`Debug` traits to provide the description of the error."

Comment: "Instead, error types should implement the `Display/Debug` traits to provide the description of the error": Are there any good examples of this kind of implementation?

Comment: `Error` requires implementing `Display` anyway, so the deprecation of `description` doesn't add any complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Add the Display implementation; that's how errors are done, now.

You can minimize boilerplate by using the [`thiserror`](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror) derive macro library to generate one for you, using strings you annotate your error type with.

Comment: Any examples for this?